# Inheritance services Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance

So I'm learning RoR and I have to 3 services that calls an API with the same structure and i want to know if i can do it with a parent class and then work with the parent class to save code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  This may work if you can define a method with fewer arguments, which builds that structure for the API call.

Approaches are:

1. Put that common method in a base class which the other classes inherit from.
2. Put that common method in a module as a mix in.
3. Write a class to handle the call to the API, which builds the structure.

I don't think you have an "isa" relationship from the sound of it.  So unless you do, 2 is preferred to 1.  You can only inherit from one class, so mixins are more flexible.

Approach 3 is a good idea.  You can have internal methods for the hostname and other constants for your API call.

This can be combined with the other approaches as you can use the Aggregation pattern to aggregate the API object in the other classes.  That might or might not make sense.  It might be just as well as the other classes have methods which instantiate the class in approach 3 and call it.